# Where does my secondary IP come from?

Tags: archlinux, ethernet, dhcp, static-ip

My Pi is configured with Arch to use eth0 with a static IP configured in conf.d:

```
[gotschi@berry ~]$ cat /etc/conf.d/network@eth0

address=10.0.55.5
netmask=24
broadcast=10.0.55.255
gateway=10.0.55.254
```

This worked better than any other configuration (e.g. netctl) for me since a few weeks. The only weird thing: It uses 2 IP addresses.
When I scan my Network Range my Pi shows up 2 Times:
One with the static IP of 10.0.55.5 and the other was assigned by my DHCP I assume           (Range set on router: 10.0.55.50-150):
10.0.55.55

nmap also reports the hostname only on the .55 address, so http://raspberry.local/ is assigned to .55

my /etc/netctl folder is empty, except for the default folders...

```
[gotschi@berry ~]$ ls /etc/netctl
    examples  hooks  interfaces
```

It also responds to 10.0.55.55 correctly!

Where are other configs stored? Thanks!

```
[gotschi@berry ~]$ ifconfig
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.55.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.55.255
    ether b8:27:eb:50:ec:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 17227  bytes 1077447 (1.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 85328  bytes 127324380 (121.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**edit**
I think I found something here:

```
[gotschi@berry ~]$ ip addr
    4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:50:ec:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.55.5/24 brd 10.0.55.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.0.55.55/24 brd 10.0.55.255 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

sudo ip addr del 10.0.55.55/24 dev eth0
disabled the second IP, just trying a reboot now

-> nope, still got 2 ip addresses :/

Comment: Could you update your post with the contents of /etc/netctl?
It may help us to diagnose the problem better. Also, try one of the examples from /etc/netctl/examples changing the necessary information and see what the result is.

Comment: That is really weird :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This helped for me:

```
update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
service dhcpcd stop
ip addr del %YOURS-SECOND-IP% dev ethX
```

And when you start raspberry pi again, **scope global secondary** will disappear.

Comment: On my side, it's erased all my ip configuration. Unable to reach my raspeberry. I've had to restart it. But it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

This happened to me too (albiet on Raspbian).
If you'd rather not totally disable the `dhcpcd` service, you can add this to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to inform it of your static interface:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24   
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

This will stop it from grabbing a secondary ip upon rebooting.

([ArchWiki Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd#Static_profile))

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by a separate dhcp@network laying in `/etc/systemd/system/`

No clue where it came from, but deleting it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

On Raspbian, I found that this situation arose from having the GUI Network Manager running while the dhcpcd service is also running.
`sudo systemctl mask dhcpcd` and a subsequent reboot took care of it.

Answer (score -1):

It is getting a DHCP IP from dhcpcd.conf and using your netplan - you can run both, I learned the hard way, I think you can even assign different IP ranges and all work - here's the trick, disable DHCP (and for fun you can rename your conf file - but - with no conf file, if DHCP is still running it will auto-use DHCP and you'll see the ip in ip a.)

systemctl stop dhcpcd

systemctl disable dhcpcd

Comment: Are you sure that archlinux uses dhcpcd?

Comment: no, I don't know - I run ubuntu (current), on a Raspberry Pi, sorry, I should have included that, but I think if you're using netplan and have this problem you should look along these lines for your solution. 1st off see if you have a dhcpcd.conf file and see if making changes to it (and rebooting) makes an IP differences so you know if you are using both or not.

Comment: But the OP uses **Arch** so your answer does not fit.

Comment: I'd still look along these lines, that is, 2 different network setups both running. Mine specifically had NETPLAN implemented and no place did anything say anything about disabling dhcpcd.conf and to my surprise, both were bring used. I must have read 100 articles on this dual IP problem and the only solutions I read that sounded viable all found 2 networking systems running. All other solution - I read about - were work arounds and not solutions ... just trying to add some thoughts on other directions to look, such as a simple true fix. Have a great day.